# How to change font in docx generated by JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, cpu-word

I am a student and a learner. I am trying to make a new web app using JavaScript for the first time but I am not able to add my font or change the font in my word document generated by JavaScript. here is my code:

```
 doc.addSection({
            properties: {},
            children: [
                new docx.Paragraph({
                    children: [
                        new docx.TextRun({
                            text: x,
                            bold: true,
                            **fontFamily: 'Myfont',**
```

Here the fontFamily is showing error:

```
                        }),
                    ],
                }),
            ],
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/docx@5.0.2/build/index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: Myfont;
      src: url('Myfont2-Regular.ttf');
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: Myfont, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>This is my first word document!</h1>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." id="myInput">

  <button type="button" onclick="generate()">Click to generate document</button>

  <script>
    function generate() {
      const doc = new docx.Document();
      var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

      doc.addSection({
        properties: {},
        children: [
          new docx.Paragraph({
            children: [
              new docx.TextRun({
                text: x,
                bold: true,
                fontFamily: 'Myfont',
              }),
            ],
          }),
        ],
      });

      docx.Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, "mydocument.docx");
        console.log("Document created successfully");
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there another syntax too so that I can style my word page format?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

[From documentation](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/styling-with-js?id=example) the tag to change font is not `fontFamily` but simply  `font` :

### Run formatting

- `bold`, `italics`, `smallCaps`, `allCaps`, `strike`, `doubleStrike`, `subScript`, `superScript`: Set the formatting property to true
- `underline({type="single", color=null})`: Set the underline style and color
- `emphasisMark({type="dot"})`: Set the emphasis mark style
- `color(color)`: Set the text color, using 6 hex characters for RRGGBB (no leading `#`)
- `size(halfPts)`: Set the font size, measured in half-points
- `font(name)` or `font({ascii, cs, eastAsia, hAnsi, hint})`: Set the run's font
- `style(name)`: Apply a named run style
- `characterSpacing(value)`: Set the character spacing adjustment (in TWIPs)

---

Here is a code sample:

```
new TextRun({
    text: "Hello",
    bold: true,
    font: "Calibri"
})
```

---

**Also make sure to use the latest version of docx.**
I was using `docx@5.0.2` and as soon as I upgraded to `docx@5.4.1` I was able to change the font.

Comment: How do you include an external font?